# redirect when on a certain path of url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a webpage that is this way `www.mypage.com/visit`
and on the page visit there are several links and each link points to an url for example:

- `www.mypage.com/visit/this/ajsjd`
- `www.mypage.com/visit/that/asdhjd`

What I want to do is when I'm on the page `www.mypage.com/visit/` it should do nothing but when the url is `www.mypage.com/vist/this/` I want to redirect. right now I'm using  `if(tab.url.indexOf("visit") != -1){//redirect}`
but this way it will redirect when I'm on `www.mypage.com/visit` and I don't want that because on this page I need to click a link and after so on `www.mywebpage.com/visit/etc/` redirect.

Sorry if this is a mess but I really don't know how to explain this better.

Comment: Often, you will get good/better response to a question if you provide a bit more of the code, html markup etc. in your question.  When you edit, there is a button (activated by CTRL-M or clickable) to provide a snippet of code with a place for HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved using a series of if

```js
if (tab.url === 'https://www.example.com/go') {

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    file: "go.js"
  });
}


if (tab.url.indexOf('/example.com/shop/all') && tab.url !== 'https://www.example.com.com/shop/carrel') {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    "file": "utilities.js"
  });
  console.log("injected");
  window.stop();
}
```

Comment: You should format this and fix the syntax errors to show a valid answer.  Glad you worked it out.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer, formatting as a snippet, removing the syntax error caused by mismatched quotes.